# The PickView is not visible when I run iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder

I drag a `PickerView` and a button to the View in my xib file.

But, when I build my code, only my button shows in the simulator. It seems that the `PickerView` has been hidden because I have got the data from the `PickerView`.

What is the reason for this problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: you post your picture in some other site and post the link in here only.and you try from starting I  think you wrong somewhere in xib.

Comment: Let me see xib and that picture

Answer (score 1):

You must implement at least 2 methods from the UIPickerViewDataSource and 1 from the UIPickerViewDelegate to have the picker view show up.  The following 3 methods create a picker view that just displays the word "text" in 3 columns and 12 rows:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return @"Test";
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 12;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And do not forget to declare your UIViewController class as delegate of UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate:

```
@interface YourCustomClassViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `YourCustomClassViewController.h` file,

```
@interface YourCustomClassViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>{
IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;

}
```

In `YourCustomClassViewController.m` file, You can add following methods

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return @"YourName";
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return 5;
}
```

In your xib file(`YourCustomClassViewController.xib`), connect   Picker to File's Owner. Like following way...

```
pickerView --->Picker

dataSource --->Picker

delegate ---->Picker
```

I hope it will be helpful to you surely. If you have any doubt ask to me.